# Relative baseurl in magento

Tags: magento

I am wanted to know that if there any settings in magento that we can remove fixed baseurl and keep dynamic(Relative) baseurl such as drupal.

Comment: what method you wanna use Mage::getUrl() ?

Comment: No my question is : We pass a value as base URL in table core_config_data. Is there any way by which we can keep relative url? So when I am accessing www.example1.com my baseurl would be www.example1.com and for same magento to website if I am accessing using www.example2.com it will work same.

Comment: you mean with different domains pointing at the same website?

Comment: Used to be allowed, was found to be a security flaw. Is no longer recommended.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to have a relative base URL, but there's a good tutorial how to set base URL by an ini file in case of live/staging. You could adapt this to your needs:

http://maglife.co.uk/2009/03/28/magento-base-urls-and-devstaging-installations/

I would change it to read the base url from an Apache variable, which you could set per virtual host or directly read it from $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].

Comment: Its not giving any solution.

Comment: Sorry for "just" pointing you in the right direction and not doing your full work ...

Comment: FYI this is the updated URL: http://jwills.co.uk/2009/03/magento-base-urls-and-devstaging-installations/

Answer (score -1):

I have found that Magento sometimes will return an incorrect protocol (HTTP/HTTPS). To bypass this I've used hard-coded [relative protocol URLs](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) in certain cases (in phtml templates only) instead of calling functions.

Comment: I clearly mentioned that I would like to have my whole website which uses relative url.